# constraint in oracle

Tags: oracle, constraint

I'm trying modeling things like this using oracle:

An account can have 1~5 members

So I'll have a account table and a member table with a FK of account. But is that possible to check if the account have less than 5 members?

I've tried constraint and trigger but oracle doesn't allow sub queries in constraint or condition of trigger like

`CHECK( SELECT ...)` or `IF count(*) >= 5`

which make things getting hard.

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f%3Fp%3D100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4233459000346171405 has some examples

Comment: I think you have to write a trigger that check the number of members when inserting or updating on the member table.

Comment: but oracle don't allow subquery in trigger, so I can't query in condition like `IF count(*) >= 5`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to add a `memberNo` column and restrict to 5 possible values, per account:

```
CREATE TABLE members
( -- ...
  accountID NUMBER REFERENCES accounts (accountID),
  memberNo NUMBER NOT NULL,
  -- ...,
  UNIQUE (accountID, memberNo),
  CHECK (memberNo IN (1,2,3,4,5))
) ;
```

This imposes of course the additional burden of providing and keeping values for this column when inserting into the table (with extra complications for deletions. If for example you delete the member with `memberNo=2` for an account, should the 3 higher numbers be decreased or should the complications be dealt in future inserts.)